# Ferramenta gratuita para wireframe de aplicativo

Tags: modelagem, ux

Qual ferramenta gratuita já usaram e indicariam para fazer o wireframe de um aplicativo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu gosto bastante da Draw.IO: https://www.draw.io/

Ela é bem genérica e flexível, dá perfeitamente para fazer wireframes e protótipos de apps, inclusive criando várias páginas e incluindo eventos de click para navegar entre as páginas, etc.

E é free :)